# How can I temporarily hide elements on a slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a slide on which I want to construct a complex animation, but all the elements on that slide make it almost impossible to construct what I want to achieve.

Is there a way to temporarily hide elements on a slide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use the **Selection Pane**.

1. On the **Home** tab on the ribbon, find the **Arrange** button and collapse the attached menu. Then open the **Selection Pane** by clicking the option with the same name.

   [image]
2. Toggle the visibility of individual elements by clicking the eye icon next to their name.

   [image]
3. Remember to click **Show All** when you're done setting up your animation, as the visibility is a permanent setting and carries over into the final presentation.